# Upload .css file after saving .scss file

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, ftp, winscp

I use Visual Studio Code and WinSCP. When I open .scss file via WinSCP the file is opened automatically by VSC – It's ok. There is an extension **Live Sass Compiler** to I could compile .scss into .css file. The problem is that .css file is created in temporary folder with random number so I always must upload the file manually by drag the file from the folder to FTP client.

Is it there any solution to upload the .css file automatically on save from the temporary folder? Thank you in advance for a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download the files to a local folder.
- Have [WinSCP monitor the folder and automatically upload any modifications (including new files)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date).
- Edit the files locally (and have WinSCP upload the changes, including the generated files).

---

For your literal question, there's [WinSCP feature request](https://winscp.net/tracker/236).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned WinSCP as your FTP client, and switching up software can be a bit of a hassle. However, I once faced the same issue, and I found a workaround with CloudMounter.

CloudMounter doesn't have a dedicated interface; instead, it mounts cloud accounts (including FTP) as a temporary local drive on your PC. This integration occurs without the need to save cloud files locally. It sets up a folder that lets you browse online files, kind of like what you do with Dropbox or Google Drive.

So, when you save a SCSS file using CloudMounter, it neatly compiles it and creates the CSS file just as if you were doing it locally.

Now, CloudMounter isn't my go-to FTP client for everyday stuff (I'm a dual pane kind of guy). CloudMounter comes into play only when I want to compile SCSS directly in the cloud.

It's not a perfect solution, but it does the job.

[Link to CloudMounter: https://cloudmounter.net/]